# Which is the best way to implement datatable in angular 6

Tags: datatable, angular6

I need to implement Datatable in Angular 6 project. I need to know which is the best way to implement it with full features. As it is confusing as we have multiple options.

I have came across multiple npms. In which i will select this 3 npms as my last options.

**1. angular-datatables, 2. angular-6-datatable, 3. datatables.**

**angular-datatables :-**  Well documented and many code samples is available, seems like i should go with this. But it is dependent to jquery and would it affect my angular project that is my major concern for this npm.

**angular-6-datatable :-** Not dependent on jquery, code samples are avialable but not that much.

**datatables :-** Looks like same as angular-datatables npm

Some one please suggest me the best way to go and why should i select that.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

use angular material table it will support all operations like sorting, filter, lazy loading etc..

for more info [read](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

refer [live example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bboaqxxqyal?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts)

Comment: We are not using material module.